# “Equivalent part on my body” or “the equivalent part of my body”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What's the correct option? The former yields zero results on Google the latter has [one](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=giKJW6DOGs3y8AXyjJaQCQ&q=%22equivalent%20parts%20of%20my%20body%22&oq=%22equivalent%20parts%20of%20my%20body%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1169.1245.0.1379.2.2.0.0.0.0.66.110.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.44...33i10k1.0.5KP9a0jFS0I). So, I'm not very sure about the correct answer.

Example sentence:

> She stood silently beside me, her shoulder and hip making contact with the equivalent parts **of/on** my body.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The sentence: She stood silently beside me, her shoulder and hip making contact with the equivalent parts of/on my body.

can be simplified by writing it this way:

She stood silently beside me, **her shoulder and hip touching mine.**

**meaning**: her shoulder and hip were touching my shoulder and hip.

The pronoun **mine** makes it unnecessary to make the sentence longer.

Comment: Such a concise and perfect answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you wanted to explain what was happening, you'd be better off saying **...her shoulder and hip making contact with mine**. It's clear, concise and neater prose.

If you insisted on your own construction, your shoulder and hip are parts **of** your body rather than **on** your body.

**On your body** is really better suited to describing tattoos, blemishes or other marks.

While preferences are personal, I wouldn't be keen on *body's counterparts* as an option.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterpart

Answer (score 0):

> She stood silently beside me, her shoulder and hip making contact with the equivalent parts of/on my body.

- of - equivalent parts of my body - standing or lying side by side.
- on - equivalent parts on my body - subject is *on* your body.

---

- under - equivalent parts under my body - subject is *under* your body (in contact).
- below - equivalent parts below my body - subject is *under* your body (probably non-contact).
- above - equivalent parts above my body - subject is *above* your body (non-contact).
- over - equivalent parts over my body - subject is *above* your body (probably in contact)

Exception:

Someone or something can be *on* you if it's not in contact with something else, particularly the ground; when referring to the other object/person in its entirety and equivalently.

Examples:

- You are standing and someone is standing **on** your feet.

  - both are not the same height, then their feet are **on** yours, there isn't an equivalency.
  - both are a similar height and holding hands then each person's parts are touching equivalent parts **of** the other's body.
- The word **to** also means beside, as long as you are not either **on** or **under**.

  - I put my hand **to** their forehead. (Implies side by side).
  - They were lying down face **up**, and I put my hand **on** their forehead.
  - They were lying down face **down**, and I put my hand **under** their forehead.
    There's no opportunity to use **of**.
- You can put your hand **on** (above or beside) or **under** a ***different*** part of someone's body (or something), without an equivalency there's nothing to be equivalent **of**.

[How do I choose between "as to", "on", "of", and "about"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76735/66746)

[Provides information “on”, “of” or “about” somthing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/11717/66746)